# Putting PHP in html div

Tags: php, html, alignment

How can I left align checkboxes and the text labels to them, which are situated both in PHP variable via using HTML and CSS

I tried like this

```
$variableWithCheckboxes = '<div id="checkboxControl'. $variableWithLables['_field']['id'].'"'. $variableWithCheckboxes.'</div>';
```

but it does not work well

Any other recommendations unless css and HTML?

Comment: Can you give an example of an output you would like to get from that code ? Using only HTML please

Comment: I don't see any styling applied to the HTML output here.  What is the resulting HTML that gets emitted to the browser and how are you trying to style it?  This sounds like less of a PHP question and more of a CSS question.

Answer (score 0):

When outputing html through php their are several common approaches.

1. Templates. The most common solution for Extensible CMS type systems is templating (Wordpress, Joomla, Drupal, etc). You write a html file with lots of `<?php echo $variable ?>` inside of them. Their are some great php extensions that make this much easier such as Twig. This is designed so templates may be re-used and easily customized in a multi-purpose CMS environment. This is probably the best and most used option. To learn about this check out Twig or get a book on wordpress front-end.
2. Raw html in the code. This is what you are attempting and as you can see is not ideal. It is error prone and difficult to read.
3. For dedicated sites or smaller sites that a template system would be over-kill I like to use a sort of inside out approach to building html. I have several helper functions that I use to build dynamic html in good formatting and it's easy to read. Example:

```
function buildAttr($attr)
{
  assert(is_array($attr), 'abilities passed to buildAttr should be an array().');
  $attr_string = '';
  foreach ($attr as $name => $value)
  {
    if (is_numeric($name))
    {
      continue;
    }
    if (is_array($value))
    {
      $value = implode(' ', $value);
    }
    $attr_string .= ' ' . $name . '="' . $value . '"';
  }

  return $attr_string;
}

function htmlWrap($tag, $content, $attr = array())
{
  return '<' . $tag . buildAttr($attr) . '>' . $content . '</' . $tag . '>';
}

function htmlSolo($tag, $attr = array())
{
  return '<' . $tag . buildAttr($attr) . '>';
}
```

Using it would look a little bit like:

```
$output = '';

// Label.
$attr = array('class' => array('label'), 'for' => $name);
$output .= htmlWrap('label', $this->label, $attr);

$attr = array();
$attr['name'] = $this->id;
$attr['type'] = 'text';
$output .= htmlWrap('input', '', $attr);

// Wrapper.
$attr = array('class' => array('field', 'text', $name));
$output = htmlWrap('div', $output, $attr);
return $output;
```

Important note that any time you output user input as html you need to protect against XSS and HTML injection attacks. So any user input you pass into these functions should first pass through a sanitize function. Somthing like:

```
function sanitize($data)
{
  if (is_null($data))
  {
    return '';
  }
  assert(is_string($data) || is_numeric($data) || is_bool($data), 'Non-string passed to sanitize!');

  $data = trim($data);
  $data = htmlspecialchars($data, ENT_IGNORE | ENT_QUOTES);
  return $data;
}
```

Comment: In short how I could make these checkboxes appear in straght row via html and css

I tried 2 divs - the first I centered and the second I adjusted and then removed text-align:left; property but with no result

http://prntscr.com/s1cf6j

Thanks in advance

Comment: assume you have 5 inputs. `<div class="checkbox-wrapper"><input type="checkbox" name="a"><label for="a">hello</label></div>`. Now css `.checkbox-wrapper {float: left;}`
Live example: https://jsfiddle.net/7s1arvcy/

Comment: Of course if you are wrapping the whole thing in another div you may need to set the width of the wrapper to make sure their is enough space.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<?php
if(isset($res)){    
?>
    <div id="checkboxControl <?php echo $variableWithLables['_field']['id']; ?>"> </div>
<?php 
    }
?>
```

Comment: My intention is that the php section to serve like unique ID and the space will ruin the whole thought. The idea is "the div element + id(the php part glued to it to ensure id uniqueness + the end of the div element". The problem is , when I execute the code above it shows the checkbox(in the variable mentioned) list but without the first checkbox. I hope it is clearer now.

Comment: Could you explain more